# How can I avoid repeated numbers in a bidimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a bingo card generator, but I'm facing an issue with repeated numbers. Here's the problem: I need to create a bingo card with 3 rows and 9 columns, where each row contains 4 zeros and 5 different random numbers ranging from 1 to 90.

Here's my current code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class BingoCardGenerator {

    public static Integer[][] generateBingoCard() {
        int numRows = 3;
        int numCols = 9;
        int randomNumbersPerRow = 5;
        int randomNumberBound = 90;
    
        Random random = new Random();
        Integer[][] bingoCard = new Integer[numRows][numCols];
        for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
                // Initialize all spots to 0
                bingoCard[row][col] = 0;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbersPerRow; i++) {
                // Choose a spot to assign a random number
                int indexToAssign = random.nextInt(numCols);
                // Make sure we haven't already chosen it
                while (bingoCard[row][indexToAssign] != 0) {
                    indexToAssign = random.nextInt(numCols);
                }
                int numToAssign = random.nextInt(randomNumberBound) + 1;
                bingoCard[row][indexToAssign] = numToAssign;
            }
        }
    
        // Print the bingo card
        for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
                System.out.printf("%2d ", bingoCard[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return bingoCard;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateBingoCard();
    }
}
```

However, I'm encountering repeated numbers in the generated card. Can anyone help me modify the code to ensure that each row contains 4 zeros and 5 different random numbers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a restriction on the assignment, or are you allowed to make a class BingoCard?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an Arraylist filled with the values you need (you can do that with a for loop) and then you can get a random number from index 0 to the Arraylist's length - 1 and then remove that index;
that may look like this:

```
// In here you create an arrayList with the length of the number range and initialize it.
List<Integer> lst=new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++){
    lst.add(i);
}

// In the loop for getting the random numbers
int ind=random.nextInt(lst.size());
bingoCard[i][j]=lst.get(ind);
lst.remove(ind);
```

Hope this helps.